# Get list of k8s pod using ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, devops, kubernetes-pod

Want to get the list of pods ussing ansible.
HEre is the approach I did

```yaml
# tasks file for elasticsearch_secure
- name: Fetch podd deatils
  k8s_info:
   kind: Pod
   field_selectors:
    - status.phase=Running
   namespace: <ns>
  register: pod_list
  become: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I am getting connection time out

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
  "Failed to get client due to HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<clusterip>', port=6443):
   Max retries exceeded with url: /version
   (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x1081d5d00>:
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))"}
```

IS there anyother way I can get podd details

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
$ pip3 list | grep openshift
openshift           0.11.2
```

Please pour your suggestion stucked here.

Comment: How did you set the info for connecting to the K8S cluster? What `K8S_AUTH_*` env vars did you defined? Looks like the module is trying to connect to '138.1.32.9:6443', is this your cluster?

Comment: yes this is my cluster

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems to be a problem with Python's `kubernetes` module: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1333

What worked for me was to uninstall the `kubernetes` and `openshift` modules and install them again with the compatible versions for `openshift==0.11.2`:

```sh
# Uninstall kubernetes and openshift
$ pip3 uninstall -y openshift kubernetes

# This command also installs kubernetes
$ pip3 install -Iv openshift==0.11.2

# Installed versions
$ pip3 list | grep -e openshift -e kubernetes
kubernetes                 11.0.0
openshift                  0.11.2
```